# Angular2 : How to handle async Pipe and conditional styling?

Tags: angular, subject, angular-pipe

I am looking forward to color some asynchronously received data in green or red, depending on its value.

To take care of race conditions, I used a Subject, which broadcasts an Object containing the data that I'm interested in.

I succeeded in doing what I wanted, but the resulting code is quite ugly  :

`<span [ngClass]="{greenClass: isPositive((mySubject | async)?.fieldData), redClass: !isPositive((mySubject | async)?.fieldData)}">
    {{(mySubject | async)?.fieldData | number:'1.0-1' }}
</span>`

Is there a better way to tackle this ?
I tried to put a ternary expression in ngClass but it didn't work.
Moving code back to my controller is a no-go as it would result in the creation of ten variables straight away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `*ngFor` to get a refernece to the subject value once it resolves to a value from the subscription like so:

```
<span *ngFor="let subject of [(mySubject | async)]"
      [ngClass]="{greenClass: isPositive(subject?.fieldData), redClass: !isPositive(subject?.fieldData)}">
    {{subject?.fieldData | number:'1.0-1' }}
</span>
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5IxvngN56Vrb1MuqmrwI?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, it enabled me to move the ngFor in the parent div and remove a lot of messy code.

Comment: Very nice little trick to use the async pipe on the view without conditionals!

Comment: This was an old answer so I am leaving it but there is now syntax for using an async pipe and an `ngIf` and assigning it to a variable which accomplishes the same as the above but is less hacky. https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable